# Prisma query with NOT always returns 0

Tags: postgresql, express, prisma

I am trying to filter out all the entries that have a PRIVATE enum in them. I think it is an issue with enumerated lists. Would it be better for me to convert my ENUM to a model and then query against that?

Here is my query:

```
        count = await prisma.user.count({
            where: {
                NOT: {
                    types: {
                        has: "PRIVATE"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my schema:

```
enum UserType {
    PRIVATE //user does not show up anywhere on site. Posts are made anonymously.
    PAID //user charges for their content
}

model User {
    id                   Int                        @id @default(autoincrement())
    types                UserType[]
}
```